# keras model load error

Tags: python, keras

I saved my model post training successfully using

```
model.save("my_model.h5")
```

Now, when I try to load model using `load_model`, it gives the following error

```
model = load_model("my_model.h5") 
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 8 layers into a model with 0 layers.
```

My code :

```
model = create_model(layer_sizes1, layer_sizes2, input_shape1, input_shape2,learning_rate, reg_par, outdim_size, use_all_singular_values)
model.summary()
model = train_model(model, data1, data2, epoch_num, batch_size)
model.save("my_model.h5")
```

This saves the model, but when I try to `load_model` it gives above mentioned error .

Model is neural network with three hidden layers. Model definition u can find here : https://github.com/adakum/DeepCCA

Comment: Are you using custom layers?

Comment: No. I am new to keras and trying to run this : https://github.com/VahidooX/DeepCCA

Comment: please give more context to what you're doing. Write a minimal reproducible code so that we can see where can the error come from.

Comment: @NassimBen added few extra details .

Comment: what is your version of keras and backend ?

Comment: backend : theano, keras v : 2.0.1

Comment: Could you provide us a full code (also with importing?)

Comment: Did you train the model in  lower version keras?

Comment: I have the same problem when I try to load a saved model... Is there a solution finally ?

Comment: You are calling `create_model()` function. Are you importing it properly.?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you need to directly add `input_shape=(X.shape[1],)` in your first layer. For example, shape of your X is 10 rows and 100 columns. You need to add `input_shape=(100,)` to your first layer